# Intermittently getting exception that states "FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file" in C# program

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

When calling `File.WriteAllText` to generate files, intermittently the c# windows form program will hit a catch block due to an Exception with the message of **"FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file. For support for devices like 'com1:' or 'lpt1:', call CreateFile, then use the FileStream constructors that take an OS handle as an IntPtr."**

The stacktrace shows `Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SafeCreateFile` as being where it got to last.

After days of researching and trying to find out why this was happening, most articles talk about the reserved file names like com and etc. However, this exception is hit in the middle of exporting files after getting through a few files already. These files don't have any reserved names in them. They all have the same path except for at the end of the file name where a hyphen and padded number for which file it is on is added. Since this gets through similar named files, I believed that this wasn't what was actually happening. The other issue is I could do the same export process multiple times and not get it to happen every time. In fact out of 100 or so export processes it would maybe happen only once even though nothing in the name or path had changed.

Today I found a way to actually get it to happen almost every time. If I go to Chrome and open say **"a.singlediv.com"** to test with, start the export, then as the export is running I repeatedly reload the div site, it will 99% of the time halt the export and hit the exception mentioned above.

**Does anyone have any advice that could lead me to why this Exception message is shown for doing this? Task Manager doesn't seem to have any glaring issues with Memory or CPU overload and a log is being posted to our SQL server after hitting the Exception so I also dont believe it is a network issue.**

## Update

I was able to find out more about when the error happens with testing yesterday. When refreshing the website repeatedly, I tried a couple different ways of exporting to get more information.

A custom configuration file, a text file, and an excel file are used as setup files for our program. **I made identical folders on the Desktop and on a mapped drive which points to a folder located on our server for where the setup files are located as well as where the exports will be saved.** I tried a couple different ways of loading these files and export locations.

If I load the setup files from the Desktop folder and save to the Desktop, or load from the Desktop folder and save to the mapped drive, or load from the mapped drive and save to the Desktop folder all of these don't seem to hit the Exception. So far the only way I have gotten the Exception to occur is when I load from the mapped drive and save to the mapped drive while doing the constant refreshing of the div website.

**Attached below is a screenshot of the `Exception.ToString()` (Except for our custom methods that called `File.WriteAllText()` before in the StackTrace). I manually added returns between each method call so that it is easier to read.**

[image: Exception.ToString()]

## Workaround Update

Per Mason's suggestion I wrapped my `File.WriteAllText` call in a Polly Retry which has seemed to so far allowed the export to finish every file while debugging the code.

I first did a `RetryPolicy.Execute` that wrapped the `File.WriteAllText`. Before `File.WriteAllText` I wrote the Attempt # it was on to the Output window and after it wrote a message about completing. I did get an Attempt #2 but was getting Attempt #1 and completed for every time it was called which was not easy to see since it happens over 2000 times. So I tried to add an if statement to check if this was not the first attempt and if it wasn't it would write the Attempt # and that the retry handled Exception to the Output window. However, after adding these if statements I didn't get any Attempt #s and it didn't break on the Exception but I also saw that the Output window did have a line about hitting the Exception so I assume that means that the Retry handled it? I would of expected to see `Attempt #2` and `Retry handled Exception` around the Exception message in the Output window since it didn't stop and created every file needed. I have added a code snippet of what I added below.

```
int attempt = 0;

Polly.Retry.RetryPolicy retryIfException = Policy.Handle<System.NotSupportedException>().Retry(3);

retryIfException.Execute(() =>
{
   if (attempt>0)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Attempt #{++attempt}");
   }
   File.WriteAllText(saveLocation, this.currentFileText.ToString());
   if (attempt>1)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Retry handled Exception");
   }
});
```

Comment: I am not clear how Chrome factors into this. You've got Chrome running, and your windows form program somehow interacts with it?

Comment: I used Chrome to see if I could force the Exception to appear to Debug. I thought possibly there was something else outside of the program that was taking resources away from the program and causing it to hang up when exporting. However, I was able to have 4 different instances of the program running and all exporting at the same time and the Exception was not hit. I was even able to have one instance of the program start one export, make a change to the setup, then start a second export and both were running at the same exact time and had no issues.

Comment: But does your program interact with Chrome, normally? (What does it do, if that's not confidential information?)

Comment: What directory are you writing to? It's not the the Temp directory, is it?

Comment: The program doesn't interact with Chrome at all when exporting files. In a simplified explanation of it, `File.WriteAllText` is taking a list of points and writing them to a text file that has a custom extension.

Comment: @ObiJakobe `save to the mapped drive` that's the problem. Mapped drives exist only for interactive sessions, for a specific user. A website running under a service (non-interactive) account won't see them. Use the actual UNC path to the shared folde instead

Comment: Since I was limited with how long my comment could be, **I have added an Update section at the bottom of my question** after finding out more about when the Exception gets hit as well as answering your question where the Directory is located that I am exporting to.

Comment: @ObiJakobe why are you using a mapped drive instead of the shared folder path?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The way the winforms application works is that a client will choose the setup files and save location for exports either by an `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog` to choose the folder either to load the setup files from or the folder to export the files to. The users that noticed an issue with the program do not know what a mapped drive is, the difference between a mapped drive and the corresponding shared folder path to that drive, or how to even use the shared folder path as the path to save to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately, after seeing your comment I tested with using the shared folder path for the path in the `OpenFileDialog` and the `SaveFileDialog` instead of clicking on the mapped drive and still hit the Exception.

Comment: File dialogs work just fine with shared folders. If they didn't *no* Windows application would work with shared folders since the 1990s. Those dialogs are provided by Windows itself and used by all applications. What's the *exact* exception text? Not just the message but the full text returned by `Exception.ToString()`? And where is that shared folder located? An actual Windows computer in the same domain? Or a SAMBA server running on a slow Linux device ? Is it a real shared folder or a WebDAV endpoint that's treated as a network drive by Windows?

Comment: When the error occurs, can you read the same folder on Windows Explorer? Cheap network drives are too weak to handle large file transfers for long, resulting not only in slow transfers but dropped packets and errors. Quite often they have buggy and/or old SAMBA server versions. If the file server is a Windows server, the problem is almost certainly a hardware issue (or a buggy network driver issue, something extremely unusual)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The location of the mapped drive is a folder on a PC running Windows Server in the same domain. It is an actual shared folder that is located on the Windows Server PC. I am also able to access the folder in Windows Explorer that I am trying to save to when the Exception is hit. The `Exception.ToString()` is linked below (Except for our custom methods that called `File.WriteAllText()` before in the StackTrace). I manually added returns between each method call so that it is easier to read.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was not able to add the `Exception.ToString()` in a comment so I added it to the Update section of the question

Comment: You shouldn't add it in a comment anyway. All relevant information should be edited into the question itself. If you're looking for a quick workaround, you could wrap a retry strategy around your File.WriteAllText method, perhaps using Polly. We do this with most file system interactions we do, just because we've found file systems to be so unreliable.

Comment: @mason this seems to have allowed it to get every export completed in my testing Environment. I will try releasing this to our clients in the next update and see if this fixes the issues they were having as well. I did have an issue with trying to check and verify that I could get it to keep hitting the exception multiple times and see that the retry worked in displaying something to the output window while debugging.
I have added what I tried to do in the Output window and my Retry code as an WorkAround Update section in my question.

Comment: @ObiJakobe, I imagine you already figured out why you're not seeing `Retry Handled Exception`, but just in case... it's because `attempt` never gets incremented. The increment operation occurs inside a block that starts with `if (attempt > 0) ...`